# How to set up a one-to-one relationship in EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Let's say I have two tables, Person and Address, which have a one-to-one relationship (one-to-one or one-to-zero to be precise.) Person has an Id field which is the PK and Address has a PersonId field which is the PK/FK and matches the Person PK. So far so good.

My problem is this - I save address at the same time I save person. Person's PK is auto-generated, so I end up doing this:

1. Save Person table fields.
2. GET Person object I just saved from SQL (another call), and get its generated Id.
3. Save Address table using the Id I got in step #2.

Is there a better way to do this? Making 3 db calls seems silly.

P.S. - feel free to edit the title, I couldn't summarize the q in a sentence.

Comment: Please tag your database-related questions with the appropriate RDBMS you are using, such as [sql-server] or [mysql].  That way if there is a database-specific solution that can be presented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity framework do it for you by itself.
The way is, you need to fill you person entity as well as your address entity too.

For Example your Person entity model is

```
public class Person{
    public int PersonId {get;set;}
    public string PersonName {get;set;}
    public Address PersonAddress{get;set;} 
   //You must have this field (PersonAddress) if you created model from
   // database having both the tables relations.
}
```

Now your address entity model is

```
public class Address{
    public string City{get;set;}
    public string State {get;set;}
    public string Country{get;set;}
    public int PersonId{get;set;}
}
```

Now what you have to do is,

Fill your person entity as

```
Person person = new Person();
person.Name = "ABC";
person.PersonAddress = new Address(){ City="DEF", State = "OPQ", Country="XYZ", /*Leave PersonId*/ };
```

Save this entity in database

```
 context.entity(person).state=EntityState.Added;
 context.SaveChanges();
```

This will save both the entities, person and address and will also have relation in it. You can check that it will save PersonId in Address field.

Comment: Awesome. //post length

Answer (score 0):

Use this command for the PK/FK of the 2nd insert:

```
LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Comment: Two immediate questions here. One - is this possible in entity framework? I am not saving through direct SQL commands. Two - what if another user inserts a Person in the meantime? This controller method is async, and there could be tens of thousands people hitting it - unlikely but possible. +1 for the idea though.

Comment: 1. I use that command through PHP and it works fine.  2. If you plan on having that many users at once then I suggest you stick with your current usage.